# How can i download a file faster?

Tags: c#, file, download, queue

I have made a download program in C#. It is a queue downloader.
You can see how it works here: Click [Express Downloader](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5n7f7dbx8l93tw9/Express%20Downloader.exe?dl=0)

Is there any faster method to download?
Here is the method i use, it must support resume support.

```
private void Download(object startPoint)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                //int startPointInt = Convert.ToInt32(startPoint);
                Int64 startPointInt = Convert.ToInt64(startPoint);
                webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                webRequest.AddRange(startPointInt);
                webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                Int64 fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;
                strResponse = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                if (startPointInt == 0)
                {
                    strLocal = new FileStream(txtPath.Text + "\\" + filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                }
                else
                {
                    strLocal = new FileStream(txtPath.Text + "\\" + filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
                }
                int bytesSize = 0;
                byte[] downBuffer = new byte[4096];
                while ((bytesSize = strResponse.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    strLocal.Write(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
                    this.Invoke(new UpdateProgessCallback(this.UpdateProgress), new object[] { strLocal.Length, fileSize + startPointInt });

                    if (goPause == true)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
        finally
        {

            strResponse.Close();
            strLocal.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Get faster broadband?

Comment: @MattWilko DING DING DING. We have a winner!

Comment: You can look into http compression: http://compositecode.com/2009/03/24/using-http-compression-for-faster-downloads-with-net-c/

Comment: Use `WebClient` which encapsulate all this work for you and have a varsity of methods async and sync

Comment: WebClient sucks, with that i can not download file over 2GB... And my download speed "on steam" i a round 13.4 MB/s... so i want my program to download at around that speed too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do two things,

1. Get faster bandwidth
2. Change block size from 4096 to something like 8192 or any number which can be hold in memory easily.

Comment: Can i make a method that checks how high the block size can be? Like some code that analyses the computer... and finds highest block size available?

Comment: In ideal scenario, I guess you can have block size upto your RAM size. But I would suggest block size of 64MB

Comment: So is there any code that can analyse computer specs for an optimal block size?

Comment: So setting is to 64 mb, then i need to write 64000 in the buffer?

Comment: Actually it is 64000000

Comment: Ohh yeah, 64 mb in kb is 64000 and 64000 in bytes is 64000000.... that makes sense. Thanks dude. And can slow computers handle a big block size?

Comment: Modern day computers can definitely handle it, not sure about slow computers or system with FAT file system format.

Comment: Is there any code to optimize that? Maybe a textbox where people can enter the size they want?

Comment: In general, users aren't smart. So, I suggest you to give the number based on your intelligence and not rely user input